# Question about regular expressions

Tags: regex, character-class

I saw this statement

```
$name = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.]", "", $name);
```

What is the difference between `[^A-Za-z0-9.]` and `[A-Za-z0-9.]`?

Based on my understanding of regular expression, the `[]` is used to include all valid characters for replacment in function `ereg_replace`.

Then what is the purpose of including `^` into the `[]`?

Thank you

Comment: On a side note: `ereg_replace` is deprecated, new code should use `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The initial `^` inside a character class `[…]` inverts the set of characters that are described inside the character class. While `[A-Za-z0-9.]` matches one character of the character set described by `A-Za-z0-9.`, `[^A-Za-z0-9.]` matches any other character except one of the characters described by `A-Za-z0-9.`. What these other characters are depends on the base character set the string is defined with.

So `[abc]` matches either `a`, `b`, or `c` and `[^abc]` matches any other character except `a`, `b`, and `c`. Your example code will remove any characters that are not described by `[A-Za-z0-9.]`. That leaves only characters of `[A-Za-z0-9.]`.